# Drupal 7 adding a author profile above posts articles or blogs

Tags: drupal

I am trying to add byline style profiles for bloggers and columnist at the top of their blog or column kind of like on rabble.ca. Now I tried using 'Author pane' but it doesn't let me configure the fields I want, i.e. I don't need a join date, or online now nor even a last seen. Just a simple 'who-are-you'.
i imagine the box and shadows would be done with a style....
any help would be appreciated.
thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the required fields to the user;
2. Create the variables in your
   template.php file's preprocess function (check the node type).
3. Modify the blog node template (copy node.tpl) and add the variables created
   in step 2.
4. Style up the page as you like

These are the steps. If you are not sure how to do all this, I can go into more details.

Comment: thanks, completely missed this reply.
As to me editing files...it's like 2 worlds colliding ;)
but I will give it a whirl once I get the permission problem sorted out.